# how to prevent Browser cache in php and html?

Tags: php, caching, header

I have this issue. 
I have this website that use this lines to prevent cache, located on header at the top of the page:

```html
<?php 

header ("Expires: Thu, 27 Mar 1980 23:59:00 GMT"); //la pagina expira en una fecha pasada
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); //ultima actualizacion ahora cuando la cargamos
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //no guardar en CACHE
header ("Pragma: no-cache");

?>
```

After this, I have these lines:

```html
session_start();
header("Cache-control: private");
if($_SESSION['Nick']=='') {
include("login.html"); exit; }
include("access_data.php");
```

That works with this form on HTML

```html
<form name="frmfiltro" method="post" action="quality.html"> 
<input name="descripcion" id="descripcion" size="50" maxlength="50" type="text"> 
<!--<input name="op" id="op" type="hidden">  -->
<input name="button" id="button" value="Search" type="submit"> 
<input name="button3" id="button3" value="See new Documents" onclick="Procesar()" type="button"> 
</form>
```

Below tha page is this snippet calling to get database info:

```html
<?php //conectarse a la base.

include_once("access_data.php");
$acc = new Acceso_a_datos();
$encabezado="";
if ($descripcion!=""):
$Sentencia= "select a.*, b.descripcion as descrequisito from isoversiones a, isorequisitos b where a.requisitoiso = b.requisitoiso and (a.descripcion like '%$descripcion%' or a.codigo like '%$descripcion%' ) ORDER by b.orden,requisitoiso, descripcion, codigo, a.orden";
else:
$Sentencia=  "select a.*, b.descripcion as descrequisito from isoversiones a, isorequisitos b where a.requisitoiso = b.requisitoiso ORDER by b.orden, requisitoiso, descripcion, codigo, a.orden";
endif;
```

What am I doing wrong? cause the page  does not load new documents. Apparently, the cache headers are not working, and how can I improve them in my site.html?

Comment: Session needs to be started **before** any output. Even headers.

Comment: So, are you suggesting me to write this:?

Comment: session_start();

Comment: header ("Expires: Thu, 27 Mar 1980 23:59:00 GMT"); //la pagina expira en una fecha pasada
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); //ultima actualizacion ahora cuando la cargamos
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //no guardar en CACHE
header ("Pragma: no-cache");